# Replace Cell with value using positional location of cell

Tags: python, pandas, replace, position, row

I have the following sample dataframe below:

```
ID Text  Value
A  yes      1
C  no       1
```

I want to replace the 1 value associated with ID 'C' in the second row with 0.  Traditional ways of replacement that I found online (using .replace) would replace both 1s with 0.

Below is my desired data set:

```
ID Text  Value
A  yes      1
C  no       0
```

Comment: You can use `.loc` or `.iloc` instead of replace. Somethink like: `df.loc['C', 'Value'] = 0`

Comment: Or if you want to change values in every row where Text is 'no', use: `df.loc[df['Text']=='no', 'Value'] = 1`

Answer (score 2):

How about using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which is label based indexing:

```
df.loc["C", "Value"] = 0
```

Or use [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) which is index based:

```
df.loc[1, "Value"] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.where`

```
np.where(df.ID=='C',0,df.Value)
Out[260]: array([1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for specially use of positional location. It is possible to do it in 2 way. Using `loc` and `iloc` (numeric position).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'C'],
                   'Text' : ['yes', 'no'],
                   'Value' : ['1', '1']
        }
        )

# set the id as index
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

# use index to raplace value
df.loc['C','Value'] = 0

# reset index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)


# same operation can be done using iloc
# as an example use numeric position to revert back
df.iloc[1, 2] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

petezurich has the right answer. Just expanding on it a bit.

`df.loc["C", "Value"] = 0`

Instead of "C" in the first tuple value you can use a mask. So in your data sample it could something like
`df.loc[df['ID'] == 'C', "Value"] = 0`

or

`df.loc[df['Text'] == 'no', "Value"] = 0`